# How to maintain Forms authentication session state between Azure Web Roles?

Tags: asp.net, azure, session-state

I have deployed a RIA Services enabled Silverlight Business application on Azure that uses Forms authentication.

To enable Forms authentication on Azure, I have implemented the Table Storage providers from the Azure Toolkit. It almost works, but I have problems with keeping the session state. After I have logged in, and repeatedly presses F5 to refresh the page I switch between being logged in and logged out.

I have two Web Role Instances, and if I disable one of the it works like a charm. But as soon as I enable the second instance it's back to this sporadic behaviour. So clearly the state is not preserved because of the load balancing. Fine, I forgot to implement the Session provider, so I did:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="TableStorageSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="TableStorageSessionStateProvider"
          type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageSessionStateProvider"
          applicationName="AppAdmin"
          />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Sadly, that didn't help.

Update: The actual table (Session) is created in the Table Storage, but no data is in there.

Any ideas and/or suggestions?

Comment: Have you set your machine key in web.config?

Comment: @Ben, indeed I didn't have that. See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/f405bfdf-80b7-476a-81f9-a853455c5926 Put your comment as an answer, and I'll mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your machine key in web.config?